# ImageMagick won't compile with PNG Support on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I hope I'm missing something stupid simple.

I'm trying to compile ImageMagick from source on Ubuntu 15.10. It compiles and runs just fine, but support for PNGs is missing. Both `libpng` and `libpng-dev` are installed but ImageMagick is having none of it:

```
./configure --with-quantum-depth=8 --enable-hdri --with-bzlib=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes
...
checking for PNG... no
....
PNG               --with-png=yes              no
....
Options used to compile and link:
PREFIX          = /usr/local
EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
VERSION         = 6.9.3
CC              = gcc
CFLAGS          =  -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -mtune=haswell -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8
CPPFLAGS        =   -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8
PCFLAGS         = 
DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LDFLAGS         = 
LIBS            = 
CXX             = g++
CXXFLAGS        = -g -O2 -pthread
FEATURES        = DPC HDRI Cipher OpenMP
DELEGATES       = bzlib mpeg jbig jpeg ps tiff
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Try adding `--with-zlib` which is a pre-requisite for PNG.

Comment: Tried this and it also said `no`. `zlib1g-dev` is installed.

Comment: Have you installed `zlib` and `zlib-dev`?

Comment: There are no packages called `zlib` and `zlib-dev`, but both `zlib1g` and `zlib1g-dev` are installed.

Comment: Oh, sorry I don't know the Ubuntu version that well. It may be that the `1g` version is incompatible with ImageMagick - all I know is that the PNG delegate requires `zlib`. Maybe Glenn (@glenn-randers-pehrson) can help out as he wrote it...

Comment: *Where* is your `libpng` installed by the way?

Comment: Wherever `apt-get` put it. http://i.imgur.com/m3ASKju.png

Comment: Last attempt before I give up... maybe try doing `.configure` however you were doing it before, but then use `make libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `make install libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: I don't think it worked. I also manually changed the config files and added PNG to the list of delegates and the build just skips right over it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was but I know how to fix it.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick
```

Now I'm sure that I'm not missing any dependencies and PNG support was automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add png in the list of DELEGATES.

Try to add "--with-png"

Try adding "--with-modules"

Comment: I tried the two flags and it still did not enable PNG support. How do I add png to the list of delegates?

Comment: I don't believe *"modules"* have anything to do with it - that refers to user-written modules for customised processing not included in the standard IM suite.

Comment: Can confirm. I removed this flag and the configure script still says its lacking PNG support.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/lib/pkgconfig
```

in your environment, where /path/to/lib is the directory that contains libpng.so